# Objects with "no references" in hprof

Tags: jvm, visualvm

I'm investigating an `hprof` file in VisualVM

The server is running JDK 1.4.2_30 and has 1 GB heap with NewSize of 200 Mb.

The hprof shows 71% of the heap occupied by 56000 instances of `int[]` and none of these 56K arrays have references when viewed in VisualVM

As per us, this should have been garbage collected if there were "no references". 
So the questions are:

a) is there any way to find out these references?

b) Is this an incorrect snapshot - i.e. did the action of taking the heap dump do some sort of GC ?

c) Should we be looking at the "retained sizes" objects in VisualVM?

**As an update** - we still dont know what these `int[]` are, but the next largest objects were Weblogic internal EJB references in Pool, and we discovered an incorrect setting in one of those which has brought down memory util to 30% from earlier frequent Full GCs

Comment: This looks strange. How did you get the heapdump hprof file?

Comment: I see. Sometimes the heap dump contains instances with no references. Are you sure that all of 56000 instances of int[] are without references? Which version of VisualVM do you use?

Comment: kill -3 invokes GC before doing heap dump.

Comment: @Tomas: You are right, some of them do have references. We did not dig that far. VisualVM 1.3.2

Comment: In general there are situations, when some of the object on the heap does not have references. If you want, I can take a look at it, but I need to have your heap dump.

Comment: @Tomas: We have fixed some other config part of the application, and now are seeing a different pattern. Thanks for offering. If you can put in your comments about the invoke GC and no references into an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: For the record, I'm seeing a similar situation, though it's only ~12% of my heap, rather than ~70%. My personal guess it that they may be allocated to hold some internal JVM data-structures, but it's really just pure guessing.

Comment: Could the objects with no references be suitable for garbage collection?

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer:* guesswork ahead, I don't have a clear answer, but I might be able to give some useful hints.

I've seen a similar situation lately ('though with a much more current Java version).

The reason for the big number of unreferenced `int[]` *seems* to have been mapped buffers of some kind (I'm not a NIO expert, but it seems to have been related to this).

The reason for this conclusion is that there was a *very similar* number of `byte[]` around with pretty much the same size in memory and those `byte[]` were referenced by some `*Channel` instances.

So my guess is (was) that those `int[]` are actually *synthetic* instances that actually share their memory with the `byte[]` (which *are* properly referenced). In short: they are red herrings.

All of this is a lot of guesswork and I never followed up with it, because the actual problem at that time turned out to be something entirely unrelated.

Comment: @Tomas: I don't know if you're directing this towards me, but (as far as I remember, it's been a while) I simply created a heap dump from within VisualVM.

Comment: @Joachim I am sorry, the question should be directed to JoseK.